# Getting the writable operation error while using oracle cdc

Tags: oracle, streamsets, oracle-cdc, logminer

I am getting the following error while connecting through oracle cdc client and my origin database is read only database but the error is database required for writable operation. please help

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01300: writable database required for specified LogMiner options
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR", line 58
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of LogMiner itself - the LogMiner dictionary requires write access to the database for all modes except *Extracting the LogMiner Dictionary to a Flat File*, which does not guarantee transactional consistency. Oracle recommends using the online catalog or extracting the dictionary from redo log files, which are the options that Data Collector offers.

See the [Oracle LogMiner documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1015913).